# unable to open database file (code 14) beginTransactionUnchecked

Tags: android, sqlite

I have search through SO and google but doesn't seem fit into my case.
My application randomly gives me this exception from multiple user logs, which never happen while I test it in the emulator nor my device.(I am running on Galaxy tab2 10.1 ,android OS 4.1.1.)
I tested it can be run successfully from development.The required android manifest permissions are in place.
Below are my codes and stack trace

stacktrace :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14) 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)                   
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:678)                     
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:323)                     
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:298)                      
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:505)                        
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:416)                        
com.framework.dataaccess.GenericDAO.start(GenericDAO.java:78)
```

Below is my singleton that instantiate SQLitedatabase

```
protected static GenericDAO getInstance(Context ctx, String sql) {

  if (instance == null) {
            try {
                instance = new GenericDAO(ctx, sql);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        if(db == null || !db.isOpen()){
            try {
                db = instance.getWritableDatabase();

            } 
         catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }   

        }

        return instance;
 }
```

and for Insertion, delete or update operation I would put in these start() and commit().

```
public void start() throws Exception{
        try{
            db.beginTransaction();
        }catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

public void commit()  throws Exception{
    try{
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    finally{
      db.endTransaction();      
    }

}


  public Cursor select(String table, String[] columns, String criteriaColValue){
     return db.query(true, table, columns, criteriaColValue, null, null, null, null, null); 
    }
```

My code throws the exception from the dao select below. Which does not call the 'start()' method.

```
 public  ArrayList<Obj> getObjList(){


           ChildDao dao                = null;
           Cursor cursor               = null;
           ArrayList<Obj> list = new  ArrayList<Obj>();

            try{
                 dao = new childDao(context);
                 cursor = dao.select(TABLE_NAME, columns, Criterea );   

                 if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                      list.add(myObjs);
                    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
                 }

            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
            finally{
                if(cursor!=null)cursor.close();
             }
          return list;
         }
```

I have no idea how the error hit and not able to reproduce it from development environment. Can anyone give me a guide where to look into ?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, does anyone has any idea ? Really hope to find out the issue  :)

Comment: I have this issue too, did find out a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late, but hope this can give a clue for whoever gets this problem. I also had a similar hard to reproduce exception:

```
unable to open database file (code 14)
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:845)
```

It could be not because of database but has to do with extra data/files allocation somewhere in an application. In my case it was bad SoundPool code. Here are the details:

[java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132509/java-lang-runtimeexception-could-not-read-input-channel-file-descriptors-from-p/27812617#27812617)