# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel

Tags: java, android

I am using crashlytics to track my app's crash. There is one bug which is quite hard to figure out.  The stack trace from crashlytics is as below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
       at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(InputChannel.java)
       at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
       at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel(InputChannel.java:39)
       at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel(InputChannel.java:36)
       at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult.<init>(InputBindResult.java:62)
       at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel(InputBindResult.java:102)
       at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel(InputBindResult.java:99)
       at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.windowGainedFocus(IInputMethodManager.java:851)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1292)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.onWindowFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1518)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I know there is one similar question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582648/could-not-read-input-channel-file-descriptors-from-parcel). But there is a bit different. And as statistics from crashlytics, the crash happens mainly in SAMSUNG android phone.

I am new to android and don't know why the crash happened and how to fix this kind of crash.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any suggestion without posting any code you tried?

Comment: Make sure you have added all the values in parcelable class in the same way as you are reading from it. Sequence must not be changed.

Comment: @ANyarThar I failed to narrow down the problem, so i just want to know where can i do something.

Comment: Do post your code of parcelable class.

Comment: @GrIsHu i search Parcelable interface in the whole project. but find nothing :(.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project? If you have not used parcelable in your project then this error indicates another problem. Please post some code so that one can understand your problem.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @GrIsHu I will do some search and update with some codes.

Comment: This is (probably) a bug in android and no solution is available at the moment. It has been reported.

Comment: @user1951805 yes, i see, but i wonder whether there is any proper solutions or suggestions to avoid or fix the bug.

Comment: I've answered to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29508653/4762282). Hope it can help you.

Comment: For me it was my device's fault I don't know what though. Restarted it and now MAGIC, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Think it's a very wide area and there could be a lot of situations which can trigger this system level exception. But maybe this example of how it was fixed in a particular project can help someone.

I experienced a similar exception:
 
**`"Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel"`** on Samsung phone:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
        at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
        at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:690)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:525)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:402)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.run(Toast.java:310)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It happened in a big old project which I got for maintenance and this floating bug occurred only after several hours. I spent quite some time on it and also read some related answers on SO regarding it and had no clue except it's a system level bug of Android, and there should be some extra data or duplicates of objects or big objects in memory etc:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32470

The last thing I could think about was SoundPool. It's not used a lot in the project - there are not more than 10 different sounds played from time to time.
 But it was the root cause! Sometimes there were floating exceptions from SoundPool **`"unable to load sample (null)"`**. And it helped to realize that SoundPool was used in a wrong way:

```
public void play(int rscId) {
...
    final int soundId = soundPool.load(mContext, rscId, 1);
    ...
    soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, 5, 0, 1f);
```

So new id was generated and sound resource was reloaded each time application called play sound method! And after certain amount of time some non related exceptions started to occur until application crashed with the **`"Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel"`** exception.
It's interesting that one of those non related exceptions was:
 **`"ExceptionHandled in unable to open database file (code 14)"`**:

```
ExceptionHandled in unable to open database file (code 14)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: 
unable to open database file (code 14)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow
(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow
(SQLiteConnection.java:845)
```

And of course it has nothing to do neither with database nor with toasts/parcels. The fix for that particular situation was very easy: just preload all sounds as it's suggested in Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

"The loading logic iterates through the list of sounds calling the appropriate `SoundPool.load() function`. This should typically be done early in the process to allow time for decompressing the audio to raw PCM format before they are needed for playback.
Once the sounds are loaded and play has started, the application can trigger sounds by calling `SoundPool.play()`."

So I moved `soundPool.load() out from play() method` and the exception :
 
`"Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel"` has gone as well as the exception `"unable to open database file (code 14)"`.

```
public void play(int soundId) {
    ...
    soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, 5, 0, 1f);
```

And **`soundPool.release(); soundPool = null`** should be called as well when it's not needed anymore. And maybe it also can have an effect on such exceptions, see details here

[Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582648/could-not-read-input-channel-file-descriptors-from-parcel/24156985#24156985)

Most probably it's not the exact situation for the original question but hope it can give some information to dig further. I.e. looking for some additional exceptions, swallowed exceptions, or wrong files/data handling.

Comment: Did you find the exact cause of this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What I described is only a trigger of this runtime exception. However, this runtime exception can be worked around by eliminating problems mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 10):

I am looking for the answer for a long time such as the others facing at this exception.

As I see it, this crash can also be triggered by the unexceptional `TextView` or `EditText` which works with the `InputMethodManager`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
    at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
    at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel(InputChannel.java:39)
    at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel(InputChannel.java:36)
    at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult.<init>(InputBindResult.java:68)
    at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel(InputBindResult.java:112)
    at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel(InputBindResult.java:109)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.startInput(IInputMethodManager.java:697)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1407)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1518)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1286)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4718)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4656)
    at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:4330)
    at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:4320)
    ...
```

When `TextView` appending text, it will make text to `Editable`, and start `InputMethodManager`. But at this time, something goes wrong in the `InputMethod` process, and it leads to fail to create `InputBindResult` which reading error from the parcel.

In this case, the workaround is very simple: DO NOT call append on textview directly, use `StringBuilder` or `SpannableStringBuilder` to build text and call `TextView.setText(text)` instead!

Comment: I don't use append, I append setText Directly inside onFocusChanged for the same TextView, and the crash is reported in crashlytics, Although it is very rare but it happens

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin do you have a fix? I see this crash very rarely when `.setText()` is called within the constructor of the TextView.

Answer (score 3):

Previous users have commented that this can be a hard bug to track down. I caused this by building a custom alert dialog (containing multiple `TextView` objects) inside of a `while` loop vice an `if` statement. The application crashed before displaying the dialog box(es).

Comment: Do you know a fix for this?

Comment: @LahiruChandima - No, sorry. I haven't been coding in Android Java since shortly after I posted my answer, so it's not a problem I've continued to encounter.

Answer (score 0):

I have meet this problem recently.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descr
iptors from parcel.
```

I search the log find following info:

> 01-01 09:07:52.164  5162  6777 W zygote64: ashmem_create_region failed
>   for 'indirect ref table': Too many open files

The problem is that I create HandlerThread repeatedly, but don't do it's quit() method, at last result in fd leaked.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler` means you have `view.post` or `view.postDelay`.
and in the post method maybe `requestFocus` or `Keyboard`