# Keep receiving eglMakeCurrent failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC report when we are not using GLSurface at all

Tags: android, android-layout, glsurfaceview

My app's keep getting crash report on Android 4.4.x devices, samsung, xiaomi:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: eglMakeCurrent failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC
   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1354)
   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createEglSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1241)
   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:1058)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1580)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1030)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5639)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

My app is not using any GLSurfaceView, using only Android standard view module.

Maybe it`s because I'm using Fragment and holding too many child views?

[image]

This doesn't happen all the time. But when it happens, I click on the launcher icon, it just keep crashing.

Any direction I should search for?

Comment: If you turn off hardware acceleration in the manifest it will probably work. My guess is that you have two many Views, and the framework is attempting to create an EGL surface for each, and failing due to device-specific resource constraints.

Comment: I'd got the [same error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29508653/4762282). I fixed that by cleaning all the memory leaks.