# Android - Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel

Tags: android, fatal-error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
    at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
    at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel(InputChannel.java:39)
    at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel(InputChannel.java:37)
    at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult.<init>(InputBindResult.java:68)
    at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel(InputBindResult.java:112)
    at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel(InputBindResult.java:110)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus(IInputMethodManager.java:723)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1338)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1519)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4187)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7390)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
```

I've been constantly receiving this crash report on my app. What can be cause this?

Comment: Can you add your source code as well?

Comment: The questions already answered. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132509/java-lang-runtimeexception-could-not-read-input-channel-file-descriptors-from-p) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664785/could-not-read-input-channel-file-descriptors-from-parcel-crash-report/29508653#29508653)

Comment: I am getting same error daily by a single app. Have you get any solution for this error?